# Issue with passing values by reference into an array

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

I have an array named **`$initValues`**, which contains strings or numeric values and using a **`foreach`** loop I want to transfer the values to the **`$values`** array and the type of each value to **`$types`**.

**Code:**

```
$initValues = ["1-2", "2-1"];
$values = [];
$types = [];

foreach ($initValues as $value) {
    $values[] = &$value; # by reference.
    $types[] = gettype($value);
}
```

As you can see in the above code, I'm inserting the value by reference in **`$values`**, which is required by a function used later on, so that can't be changed. When I execute the above code and show the result using **`var_dump($values)`**, I get the following:

```
array(2) { [0]=> &string(3) "2-1" [1]=> &string(3) "2-1" }
```

The problem with the above result is that essentially both elements of my **`$values`** array are the last element of **`$initValues`** and not both as in the desired result, which is:

```
array(2) { [0]=> &string(3) "1-2" [1]=> &string(3) "2-1" }
```

If I enter each value by value into the array the result is correct, but I'm facing a problem later on, so that's not an option. How can I modify my code, in order to produce the desired result?

Comment: You should avoid using variables passed by reference as much as possible.. as the application grows it can give you a lot of headaches..

Comment: I'm with you on that @MateiMihai, but that specific function is built-in and requires references. It's out of my hands ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an index in your foreach loop.
This should work:

```
$initValues = ["1-2", "2-1"];
$values = [];
$types = [];

foreach ($initValues as $ix=>$value) {
    $values[] = &$initValues[$ix]; 
    $types[] = gettype($value);
}
var_dump($values);
```

Comment: Fantastic idea @crystalAhmet. Upvoted! Thanks a ton!